# Subnets on hyper V

Tags: routing, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, subnet

What I'm after is a hyper V host, hosting around 6 vms.

3 of them on 1 subnet
3 of them on another

And I want them all to have internet access
The 2 subnets don't have to communicate.
I'm using server 2012 datacenter.

I've created two subnets for class C IPv4 on my hypv host, so I have my hypv host on a domain etc, and atm have 1 vm using an internal virtual switch, but no internet connection...

I've done nothing on the router or switch? Is this where I'm going wrong?

Any help appreciated

Cheers
Kyle

Comment: What's your question?  Where are you getting stuck exactly while implementing this?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I've created two subnets for class C IPv4 on my hypv host, so I have my hypv host on a domain etc, and atm have 1 vm using an internal virtual switch, but no internet connection...

Answer (score 1):

Some more details would be helpful.  Can the machines within each subnet communicate with each other?  ("ping" is a successful way to verify that.  Also, the systems should not be blocking "ping" traffic, or else you may be getting a "false negative".)

Can the systems communicate with the machine that is running HyperV?

Can the systems communicate with the gateway of the machine that is running HyperV?

Can the machine running HyperV communicate to the Internet?

One other thing you didn't indicate too clearly: are the two subnets allowed to communicate with each other?  You indicated that this communication wasn't essential/required, but is it prohibited/forbidden?

My best guess is that the problem is that the machine running HyperV needs to provide IP forwarding services.  Enable forwarding.

However, there could be other causes, like a lack of NAT ever being applied to IPv4 traffic.  Routing could be an issue.  More details may be needed to figure such things out.

Comment: Hi buddy, sorry, the host has full Internet access and the vm can't ping its host, and the two subnets communicating is no problem, not too bothered about that to be honest lol and at current the vm won't be blocking anything as it is a fresh vm, I will check if the VM can ping the gateway too

Comment: This is not really an answer and should be a comment.

Comment: @Xavierjazz : The key "answer" part was the "Enable forwarding."  However, based on subsequent comment feedback, it looks like another issue.  Kyle : If the virtual machines cannot communicate with the machine that is running HyperV, I suggest trying to fix that before worrying about Internet access.  That will probably be easier to fix.  Due to bridging possibilities, such communication isn't required to work.  There are different possible designs.  My recommendation is to start by getting the virtual machines able to communicate with the machine running HyperV.

Comment: Any suggestion where to start? My NIC has 2 virtual switches running on it? The vms are also on different IP ranges due to different subnets? Am I missing something?